# Which scenarios are correct, and what happens in each scenario for these loss functions in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am developing a new method for CNN architecture, and I am currently facing confusion between these scenarios. Only one scenario is effective for my binary image classification task, which is as follows:

```
.....   
model.add(Dense(2,activation="softmax"))
....

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                  optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, when I attempt my new architecture using the following scenario, it does not yield results; the accuracy remains stuck at 0.5:

```
.....   
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
....
    
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                      optimizer=opt,
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Additionally, when I apply my new architecture to multi-class classification using the following scenario, it also does not yield results; the accuracy remains stuck at 0.5:

```
.....   
model.add(Dense(10,activation="softmax"))
....

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                  optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now, I am uncertain about what is happening internally. For those who are curious about my architecture, it is based on the following idea:

[image]

Comment: Please add more information regarding how you process the data. Try to run your pipeline with some small size data and share the reproducible code.